# SendPingAsync makes app enter Break mode if all hosts un-reachable C#

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, ping

I'm writing one of my first apps and I have ran into a issue. When input a address that's unreachable after my foreach loop exits my App enters Break Mode, however if the foreach gets result it proceeds normally.

This is part of the code that throws the exception:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    /// Verify that input box is not blank
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inputBox.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot be left blank !", "Error");
        return;
    }

    /// Creates a list of Gateway options to try from
    string[] gatewayArray = { "cadg0", "frdg0", "dedg0", "gbdg0", "iedg0", "usdg0", "dg", "dg0" };

    /// Specifies where to get store number from
    string storeNumber = inputBox.Text;
    string pingReply;
    string pingStatus;

    clearButton_Click(sender, e);

    Ping ping = new Ping();

    foreach (string gateway in gatewayArray)
        try
        {
            /// Replace store number with "Wait" text and changes color of box to red.
            inputBox.Text = "Please Wait...";
            inputBox.Background = Brushes.Red;

            /// Pings selected store using Async method
            PingReply reply = await ping.SendPingAsync(gateway + storeNumber, 2000);

            pingReply = reply.Address.ToString();
            pingStatus = reply.Status.ToString();

                /// Displays results of Ping
                ipOne.Clear();
                ipOne.Text = pingReply;
                statusOne.Clear();
                statusOne.Text = pingStatus;
                if (statusOne.Text == "Success")
                {
                    statusOne.Text = "- ONLINE -";
                    statusOne.Background = Brushes.LightGreen;
                }
                else
                {
                    statusOne.Background = Brushes.Orange;
                }

                /// Get name of host
                IPHostEntry ipHostOne = Dns.GetHostEntry(pingReply);
                string ipOneName = ipHostOne.HostName;
                ipOneName = ipOneName.Substring(0, ipOneName.LastIndexOf(".") - 10);
                nameOne.Text = ipOneName.ToUpper();

            }

            catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            catch (PingException)
            {
                /// Catches exceptions and continues
                /// MessageBox.Show("Unreachable !");
            }
```

If I specify incorrect store number I get:

> Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' in mscorlib.dll
>       An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred 
>       in mscorlib.dll
>       StartIndex cannot be less than zero.
>
> ```
> The program '[19616] SbPinger.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
> ```

I tried to handle it with try / catch:

```
catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

However the catch does nothing and the program still enters Break mode.

My program simply pings all possible default Gateways and returns IP if its finds one, then pings the individual PC's on that network. Everything else works except when the Ping doesn't reach any gateway. Please go easy on me as I been using C# for only couple weeks. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Peter

Comment: Just a note, `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` also checks if the string is empty, so `inputBox.Text == ""` is redundant. And also wrong here, since you should *first* check for null. That said, you should also post the exception's call stack here.

Comment: Got that updated thanks for that. Also added the rest of Try / catch code.

Comment: How about the call stack? And `ipOneName.Substring(0, ipOneName.LastIndexOf(".") - 10)` looks dubious. Are you sure that there always is a `.`, and that its position is at least ten characters from the start?

Answer (score 0):

So after looking around for a while and trying different things I have found that using Dns.GetHostEntry instead of pinging the URL, yields much faster results and doesn't crash out since all the processes finish. Here's the code if anyone is interested:

```
// Get IP from DG adrress
            try
            {
                IPHostEntry hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry("URL");
                IPAddress[] address = hostEntry.AddressList;
                textBox.Text = address.GetValue(0).ToString();
            }
            catch
            {
                // Catches Exception and moves on
                // MessageBox.Show("No result", "Error");
            }
```

Thanks for the response !